# Dynamically adjust text input box width to fit reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, width, textinput

I have a text input box that accepts text and I want to adjust the width dynamically based on the input width. Based on things I tried, I can get it to change easy enough, but the box doesn't 'hug' the text well and there's a gap that remains on the right side.

```
<Input
  paddingHorizontal='8px'
  value={value}
  onChange={onChange}
  maxWidth='300px'
  minWidth='120px'
  width={value ? `${width}px` : 120px}

/>
```

Things that I have tried on the onChange handler to set the width that have not produced the desired effect:

1. This one seemed the closest, and works great while text is expanding it fits really well.
   [image]
   However, when deleting it doesn't work so great and leaves extra white space on the side
   [image]

```
const onChange = event => {
    let currentWidth;
    //if text is being deleted
    if(value && (value.length > event.target.value.length)){
      currentWidth = event.target.scrollWidth - 5;

    } else {
      currentWidth = event.target.scrollWidth + 1;
    }
    setValue(event.target.value);      
    setWidth(currentWidth);  

}
```

2. This version leaves too much space on the side while typing
   [image]

```
const onChange = event => {
    //I've tried various numbers here besides 9
    let currentWidth = event.target.value.length * 9;
    setValue(event.target.value);      
    setWidth(currentWidth);  
}
```

If you have any thoughts or suggestions on how to make the input box fit the text better please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: This is purely my opinion, but I personally think the box resizing its width is a little off-putting. Why not use a mult-line textarea if you're going to allow that much text? You can size it to fit just what you allow or allow the user to drag the height if they want to see more.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width, `fit-content` may be helpful

Comment: Thank you for replying Yatrix - fit-content didn't seem to solve my issue, but I'll keep working at it.